# Filemaker ODBC metadata missing in SSIS / SQL

Tags: sql, ssis, odbc, metadata, filemaker

I am having trouble gaining access to FileMaker Pro 11 data through the ODBC connection and starting to believe that it is not possible.

I have installed the odbc drivers supplied with the installation (11.03.76.00) locally to the FileMaker database, having worked out that they will **not** work remotely to the server.  Have setup and successfully tested a system DSN.

When I try to use that System DSN within SQL Server or SSIS (same underlying process), I am gaining access to the list of tables and can preview the data, however when each process tries to get the metadata regarding the tables it fails.

SQL lets me select the tables / columns, preview the data, match it to destination and change the data types, but then fails on the next step of checking the conversion

[image: FileMaker failing in SQL Server]

SSIS provides list of tables / columns, data preview, but fails to list the columns (im guessing because it cannot work out the types)
[image: FileMaker failing in SSIS]

FileMaker tech support does not cover the ODBC driver which has led me to believe it does not work...

Has anyone successfully attached to FileMaker Pro though the version 11 of the driver with SSIS or SQL? I need to automate a daily extract - any other ideas?

Comment: If it can preview the data, that'd imply the data can be accessed. If it's truly just an issue of typing, you'd either need to cast as a compatible data type in your query or explicitly define the column types in the source (Right click, Show Advanced Editor->Input and Output Properties) If the ADO.NET source doesn't work, you should be able to brute force it via a Script Transformation (as source) Sounds like an interesting project, best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks billinkc, had forgotten about using the Script Transformation as a source.  Managed to get the odbc driver working this way.  The root of the problem appears to be filemaker's data type mappings

Comment: Excellent! You should have the ability to add the above as an answer and close this issue out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As billinkc points (above comment - sorry cannot convert comment into an answer), you can use the Script component as a Source and program around the ODBC driver issues.

The FileMaker Pro 11 odbc driver is data type aware, but they are not plumbed in correctly.  The work around requires converting each column to string and then TryParse'ing to the correct data type.